# Camera application and MediaRecorder interfere

Tags: android

I use `MediaRecorder` inside `Service` to record audio. When audio recording is in progress, and when I try to manually start camera, I got this:

[image]

Sometimes my app crashes, and log says only "Process died".

How do I handle such situation, I mean, maybe to detect that camera app wants to record something, so that I can free `MediaRecorder`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must need to release media recorder sources as camera activity can be going to use all those same resources.

Comment: I know, I just don't know how to detect that Camera app is launching, since it's a system app and my Service doesn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to release the media recorder resources when you quit the activity.
Maybe that's the reason.
It will still exist even you finish your activity if you didn't close it.

Comment: I'm really sory, but... Hey, guys! You answering without even reading the question! My MediaRecorder works in Service.

Comment: AHA...Yeah,It's my fault.I miss the first line.

Comment: Maybe you could check the MediaRecorder in the right state before you start it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html . I guess the reason can found in MediaRecorder State Diagram.

Comment: The problem is that I have the original issue when my MediaRecorder is ALREADY working.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's not possible to listen to the hardware camera launch.

[Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) doesn't broadcast any action that would enable you to free the MediaRecorder before the error occurs. The actions broadcast by the Camera are `ACTION_NEW_PICTURE, ACTION_NEW_VIDEO, CAMERA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED`, and `CAMERA_ERROR_UNKNOWN`, neither of which would allow you to release the MediaRecorder before the error occurs.

Comment: So, I'll have to leave my users unhappy.

Comment: If you set the right expectations upfront the user will not be unhappy. Explain to the user that the camera can't be used while your app is recording because of how the Android system works. I can't claim to know how much this will limit the market appeal of your app, but it's one way to avoid disgruntled users.