# Service to detect when MediaRecorder is called by any application

Tags: android

I have an AudioRecorder app that runs in a service smoothly, but when I try to use any Recorder app (Video/Voice Recorder), it gives the following error

Voice: Unable to start a new recording. Other applications are already recording
Video: Recording failed

a similar issue was raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504298/camera-application-and-mediarecorder-interfere)

I want to know if there is any possible way to set a service to listen to when a MediaRecorder.start() is being called by ANY app or even when the object is created.
Thanks.

Comment: I am also facing same problem but never noticed .I just figured it out